# When is the unitary dual of a lscs group uniformizable?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, topological-groups, unitary-representations, uniform-spaces

Let $G$ be a locally compact, second countable group. We equip the unitary dual $\widehat{G}$ with the Fell topology. I am looking for conditions which guarantee that the topological space $\widehat{G}$ is uniformizable.

Here, a topological space $X$ is called uniformizable if there exists a uniform space whose underlying topological space is homeomorphic to $X$. Our definition of a uniform space is the one used e.g. in Bourbaki, General Topology or on the Wikipedia page for "Uniform space". Some authors require an additional axiom in the definition of a uniform space, which enforces that the underlying topological space be Hausdorff; since the unitary dual of a lcsc group is rarely ever Hausdorff, we do not want to assume this axiom here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A topological space $X$ is uniformizable iff it is completely regular. Glimm's Theorem states that a second countable group is Type I iff $\widehat{G}$ is $T_0$. Since a $T_0$ uniformizable space is Hausdorff (which can be seen easily from the pseudometric definition of uniformity), all Type I examples will be Hausdorff.

When $G$ is not Type I, Glimm's Theorem also shows that, in a precise sense, $\widehat{G}$ is a wild object that has no reasonable classification. The usual replacement for $\widehat{G}$ in this case is $\mathrm{Prim}(G)$, the primitive ideal space of $\mathrm{C}^*(G)$ with the hull-kernel topology. However, this is always a $T_0$ space, so you run into the same problem with being Hausdorff.

See [Groups with completely regular primitive ideal space](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022123675900464) by Justin Peters and the citations there for some answers to these questions, although note that his definition of completely regular is stronger than the usual definition, which he calls “topologically completely regular”.

Comment: "A topological space X is uniformizable iff it is completely regular." - What is your definition of completely regular? With the definition I know, a space is completely regular iff it is uniformizable AND Hausdorff.

Comment: @Tom I was using completely regular in the sense of points and closed sets being separated by continuous functions, without the assumption of being Hausdorff. However, the paper I cited includes Hausdorfness.

Comment: OK, just to make sure I understand: If $G$ is Type I, then $\widehat{G}$ (not $G$ as you write) is $T_0$. If $\widehat{G}$ is uniformizable, then it is completely regular in your sense (which is true also in a non-Hausdorff setting), hence Hausdorff. Did I understand that correctly?

Comment: Yes. I'll change the answer to just refer to uniformizability to avoid confusion.